# What sort of setup do I need for a wired internet connection with the outlet pictured?

Tags: ethernet

I'm trying to figure out what sort of setup I need for a wired network connection in a newly built rental home. My guess is that it's a port for a fiber optic connection, but I thought I would ask here first to be sure. Here's a somewhat grainy picture of the wall outlet in question:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that isn't a cable TV outlet?

Comment: Yep. Phone and cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a cable (coaxial) outlet. You need to check with a provider since those use DOCSIS modems that need to be set up at the provider. *Where available* fibre optic connections look nothing like that. Many places don't run fibre all the way to the home so your endpoint may differ but a fibre optic socket is usually covered with a little cap that's pretty small and not metallic. The one on top looks like an unpopulated phone socket.

At least out here both docsis and fibre connections have clearly labelled, distinct boxes, rather than a generic socket in the wall.